# Telerik Display time in kendo Client Template from integer

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik grid and am using an integer to set the Y axis.

Number of seconds, what I want to do is change the label on the chart from

```
 97 seconds
 132 seconds
```

as an interger to show time like below

```
 01:37
 02:12
```

by updating the template, this should be fairly straight forward, just cant seem to find the right syntax

```
lineSeries1.TooltipsAppearance.ClientTemplate = "#= value # seconds";
```

to be something like

```
lineSeries1.TooltipsAppearance.ClientTemplate = "#= value #.format('hh:MM:ss') ";
```

Comment: you could use moment.js with this plugin to format timepans: https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function on your template:

```
function formatTime(time) {
    var rootDate = new Date(new Date(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).setSeconds(time));

    var minutes = ("0" + rootDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("0" + rootDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

And the template as `"#: formatTime(value) #"`

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ohACA).

- *Obs #1*: Note that that function is made only for your need, with it you lost the kendo's globalization and your time would always displayed as `00:00`;
- *Obs #2*: The lib @ezanker proposed is very good tho but it is overkill imo if you only need that what you asked.

Comment: Sir can u please look on this issue, please help me sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093044/how-to-show-time-format-in-kendo-chart